# Obtaining randomForest Predictions from a dataset different from the original set

Tags: r, random-forest, prediction

The datasets where prepared as followed:

```r
library(caret)
library(randomForest)
set.seed(2242)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y = new_train$classe, p= 0.85, list = FALSE)
training <- new_train[inTrain,]
testing  <- new_train[-inTrain, ]
```

Then I trained the random forest model below

```r
model <- randomForest(classe~., data = training, importance = TRUE)
```

the predictions are successfully generated

```r
testingpredictions <- predict(model, testing[ ,-55])
```

The validation set is set as follows:
the term chosen_column is a subset of the test set which contains only the variables used in the training of the model

```r
validation_set <- test[ ,chosen_columns]
validation_set$new_window<- as.factor(validation_set$new_window)
```

## PROBLEM 1

when I try predict using the validation set which is in a different file:

```r
valpredictions <- predict(model, newdata = validation_set, type = "response")
```

I get the error

```r
Error in predict.randomForest(model, newdata = validation_set, type = "response") : 
  Type of predictors in new data do not match that of the training data.
```

## PROBLEM 2

When I use the train function with  method = "rf" and method = "gbm"
the code runs until the program crashes

## Attempted Solutions

I tried `rbind` to match the datasets but also receive an error:

```r
data <- rbind(train, test)

Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names
```

I also tried coercing all the data into the same class prior to running the models but still yields the same errors

Comment: Could you provide the output of `dput(new_train)`?

Comment: Here you use different columns for validation and train sets. So it won't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I uploaded the data and code on GitHub on https://github.com/Bonolo114/Fitbit-Project.git. @Julien

Comment: For the solution I preprocessed the data by centering and scaling the data, for some or other reason the rows were able to bind thus calibrating the data somehow. then only was I able to run on the new dataset